# Why BluetoothChat sample cannot connect?

Tags: android, sample

I am using the default android sample code "Bluetooth Chat" with HTC Hero. Search device is working and when I click on the list, it can do the pair job and display connecting on the title. But it will throw IOException when call BluetoothServer.connect().

PS: I am not connecting to a bluetooth adapter on PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fount the reason. The bluetooth adapter can only support Obex Push Object Protocol. So change the UUID to 00001105-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB is ok now.